# @article.save seems save the old content not the updated one

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model instance method called merge_with(other_article_id) in Article:

```
  def merge_with(other_article_id)
    self.comments << Article.find(other_article_id).comments
    self.body_and_extended << Article.find(other_article_id).body_and_extended
    return self   
  end
```

In my controller, I have merge defined:

```
  def merge #ypw
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    unless @article.access_by? current_user
      redirect_to :action => 'index'
      flash[:error] = _("Error, you are not allowed to perform this action")
      return
    end
    if params[:merge_with] and params[:merge_with] != ""
      @article = @article.merge_with(params[:merge_with])
debugger      
      if @article.save
debugger
        destroy_the_draft unless @article.draft
        set_the_flash
        redirect_to :action => 'index'
        return
      end
    end
    flash[:error] = 'merge articles did not succeed!'
    redirect_to :action => 'index'   
    end
```

Question: before 1st debugger break point, I check @article.body showing it already merge both articles' body "A" and "B" into one "AB" perfectly. But after continue and run @article.save at the 2nd debugger break point (@article.save did return True to allow to get into the if statement), I found that actually only the original article got save, i.e. @article.body == "A". Could anyone help me to understand what's going on? why after @article.save, the content of updated @article.body changed back to original content before update?

Thank you so much for your help.

---

Hi MrYoshiji,
Thanks for the suggestions. I tried both: save and save!

```
debugger
      #if @article.save
      if @article.merge_with(params[:merge_with]).save!
debugger
        destroy_the_draft unless @article.draft
        set_the_flash
        redirect_to :action => 'index'
        return
      end
```

no error raised. as you might expected at the 2nd debugger break point, I check @article.body and indeed shows "AB" now. But when it run thru redirect_to :action => 'index' back to the article list page, if I click on the link of merged article, then in the editor, it still shows "A" only the "B" is gone. is there possibility somewhere in between the old content got save back again?

---

Hi phoet, yes, when I run in the rails console (actually I am in rails server --debug) and merge_with behavior is as expected. as matter of fact, the two behaviors: << comments and << body are checked and alright, but interestingly after plug it into the code, only << comments part survive and << body part got lost!? after redirect_to mysteriously.....

---more on this mystery-----
Please see the interactively typing the commands in the rails server --debug console. Please see the magic/mysterious disappearing of '32' in the Article.find(33).body content right after saves (but still exists in @article.body content)...... any plausible explanation? thanks.

```
(rdb:65) @article.body
"<p>\r\n\t33</p>\r\n<p>\r\n\t32</p>\r\n"
(rdb:65) Article.find(33).body << Article.find(32).body
"<p>\r\n\t33</p>\r\n<p>\r\n\t32</p>\r\n"
(rdb:65) Article.find(33).body
"<p>\r\n\t33</p>\r\n<p>\r\n\t32</p>\r\n"
(rdb:65) Article.find(33).save
true
(rdb:65) Article.find(33).body
"<p>\r\n\t33</p>\r\n"
(rdb:65) @article.body
"<p>\r\n\t33</p>\r\n<p>\r\n\t32</p>\r\n"
(rdb:65) @article.id
33
(rdb:65) Article.find(33).body
"<p>\r\n\t33</p>\r\n"
(rdb:65) @article.save!
true
(rdb:65) @article.body
"<p>\r\n\t33</p>\r\n<p>\r\n\t32</p>\r\n"
(rdb:65) Article.find(33).body
"<p>\r\n\t33</p>\r\n"
(rdb:65) Article.find(32).body
"<p>\r\n\t32</p>\r\n"
(rdb:65) Article.find(33).body << Article.find(32).body
"<p>\r\n\t33</p>\r\n<p>\r\n\t32</p>\r\n"
(rdb:65) Article.find(33).save
true
(rdb:65) Article.find(33).body
"<p>\r\n\t33</p>\r\n"
(rdb:65) @article.body
"<p>\r\n\t33</p>\r\n<p>\r\n\t32</p>\r\n"
(rdb:65)
```

---

Hi Doug, so the only line of attr_accessible is in traceback.rb (actually this is from typo blog open source)

```
require_dependency 'spam_protection'

class Trackback < Feedback
  belongs_to :article
  content_fields :excerpt
  validates_presence_of :title, :excerpt, :url

  attr_accessible :url, :blog_name, :title, :excerpt, :ip, :published, :article_id
  ........
```

None in all other models including Article model at the subject.

Comment: Can you try `if @article.merge_with(params[:merge_with]).save` please? And try with `save!` to raise an error if it exists

Comment: did you try running your code in the rails console? is it working as expected?

Comment: This sounds like mass assignment protection, it behaves as though no change has been made. Do you have a line with `attar_accessible` in your model? Are all the fields you want to modify in there?