# rails saving parent class data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, save, associations

I'm updating information through a child object but i can't seem to get its parent object to save the data.. here's the situation.

```
class NewsPage < Content
   content_fields :body
```

Content has a column call body, so i can do as follow:

```
newsPage1.body
```

I want to do the copy the body of page2 into page1:

```
newsPage1.body << newsPage2.body
```

if I print newsPage1.body i'll get both bodies in there.. but once the request is completed the newsPage1.body will reset to its original state.. i think is because I'm not accessing Content's table when that happens... so how do I go about saving the body of the Content of newsPage1 into Content's page column? I might be wrong and this might be due to something else.. same problem as this guy, but he never got an answer:
[@article.save seems save the old content not the updated one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13479359/article-save-seems-save-the-old-content-not-the-updated-one)

EDITED to add the code from the post i linked previously:

```
  def my_method(other_id)
    self.rating << NewsPage.find(other_id).rating
    self.body << NewsPage.find(other_id).body
    return self   
  end
```

In my controller,this is called as follows defined:

```
  def copy 
    @newsPage = NewsPage.find(params[:id])
    @copiedNewsPage = @newsPage.my_method(params[other_id])

    redirect_to :action => 'main'   
  end
```

So ratings copied OK but body did not, any clues?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a bad time trying to understand your question, and with the few lines of code you wrote I'm also having troubles to have an idea of what you are doing, try by putting more code and explaining a little better your problem. If someone else cannot reproduce your problem, then he won't be able to help you.

But it sounds like a mass attribute issue, try with this code:

```
class NewsPage < Content
  attr_accessible :body
  content_fields :body
```

and let me know if it works. Thx

Comment: Thanks, the code is pretty much what's in the post i linked to in my original post. I tried your suggestion but it made no difference.. any other ideas?

Comment: with the description you gave,that's all I can guess for now... if you are able to build some code in order to replicate the issue, then I'll be able to help and fix the issue for you :)

Comment: OK edited to include the code from the linked post only trimmed down with the non important info

Comment: So why are you not persisting the updates, with @newsPage.save ? If you don't persist the updates, once you redirect the user, you will loose any update made on the object

Comment: True but for example ratings is works (it's saved).. that's because the "<<" operator saves the value to the database already. I even tried with save! (which is kind of reduntant at that point) and it wasn't working either

Comment: The operator << saves it on an "association", not on fields. If you are able to put some code where I could replicate the issue, I'll be able to help right away. What is **content_fields**, as far as I know, that's not related to active record, so it may be something related to the gem that you are using. Can you try to write more code so we can try other solutions, or even better, if you are able to write some code that reproduce the issues (so I can copy/pastle on my console), that will be much better :)